# how to add a cgi-bin script to dd-wrt

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt

Buffalo WHR-300HP2, with: Firmware Version DD-WRT v24SP2- (11/05/13) std - build 22750, on: Kernel Version Linux 3.10.18 #37 Tue Nov 5 08:17:35 CET 2013 mips.

i would like to add a shell script to the existing httpd.

seems like there may be some [problems](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=25015) with this.

thanks

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: it's in the title: how to add a cgi-bin script to dd-wrt

Comment: Wait for dd-wrt expert. Or dig deeper. Inside is some http server with logs, errors, config ...

Answer (score 0):

> [For DD-WRT V24 pre SP2 (svn 12533+) CGI support has been disabled as a fix for an exploit.](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/WEB_server#Cons)

[You can install and configure separate vlighttpd](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/WEB_server#Separate_httpd-server_for_your_site).

> Separate httpd-server for your site
>
> For the best result it is better to use separate httpd-server for your
>   site. There are several possibilities: install vlighttpd e.g. with
>   Optware, The Right Way or install Optware-ByHand and after that
>   busybox (for simple httpd) or install lighttpd. [edit] Assumptions
>
> - You have telnet and SSH enabled on your router. See Telnet/SSH_and_the_Command_Line.
> - You can install additional httpd-server to your router.
> - You can send files via SSH to and from your desktop (e.g with WinSCP)
> - You have jffs enabled and enough free space to store your files or you have some other persistent partition e.g. mmc mod or usb drive.
>     [edit] Procedure
>
> 1) Install additional www-server of your choice e.g. busybox httpd,
>   lighttpd or vlighttpd from optware
>
> 2) Move default httpd away from
>   port 80 (optional). Easiest is just to disable web administration via
>   http, https uses port 443. Other option is to set the http_lanport
>   nvram variable in the nvram:
>
> ```
> nvram set http_lanport=81 nvram commit reboot
> ```
>
> Note: Even if you plan to use secondary IP for your own site, you need
>   to move the built-in httpd away from the port 80, as it listens it's
>   port on all IP:s.
>
> 3) Optional: open to the world
>
> Caution! The following steps could make the router's management pages
>   accessible from the WAN (for example
>   http://Your.WAN.IP/Management.asp). The password should be required
>   however, so make sure it is strong.
>
> Open web admin Administration -> Diagnostics, press "Run"
>
> Enter this line to the Commands field:
>
> ```
> /usr/sbin/iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j logaccept Press "Save Firewall", the router will reboot or reboot it manually.
> ```
>
> How to cancel this?
>
> Telnet to the router and type:
>
> ```
> nvram set rc_firewall=""
> nvram commit
> reboot
> ```

Comment: this requires jffs. i have no way enabled jffs in my web interface.

Comment: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices#Buffalo
It sad, tut there too smal Flash and no USB for external flash.

Comment: Look like dd-wrt use own implementation of http server to fit in small flash. But security sacrificed.